# Is there way to show a local html file on my hosted website if the file exist on the machine?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, web-hosting

I'm a new web developer and I am trying to demo an html page to someone.

I have a website built and hosted and when a button is clicked I want to show this html page. the catch is that the html page and its corresponding js file are not ready yet to be hosted on the server. So I was wondering if there is a way to redirect to the local version saved on the machine in a specific directory (e.g. D: project/ demo.html) instead?

I know there are security concerns when it comes to this and most browsers don't allow such access. In my case I just need it to run in this manner on my own machine.

Comment: You can host it locally

Comment: You can host it on localhost and then use something like ngrok to make it accessible through the web.

Comment: Can you run the whole site locally on your machine?  Usually for development you would have a full copy of the site on your own computer.